# How can I adjust the volume of headphone and laptop speaker separately?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How can I adjust the volume on my headphone and laptop speakers separately? For example, I want to mute my laptop speakers but on my headphone, I want it on 50. Is there anyway I can adjust them differently?

Comment: Doesn't your laptop speaker cut out when you plug in the headphones?  If you set the volume at 50, just plugging in the headphones should accomplish both.

Answer (score 1):

It is the onboard sound solution that shows up in Playback devices not your headphones or speakers. Both the headphones and speakers use the same solution.

You can set the Realtek software to disable the sound to the speakers when you plug in your headphones, or just disable auto-detection and turn your speakers off manually then plug in your headphones.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Sound Driver’s Audio Control Panel, like Realtek audio control panel to configure the volume separately.

Here is a reference:

https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-auto-adjust-volume-for-headphones-in-windows-10/